# Proving units of $Z[\sqrt{d}]$ with the norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Greetings my quetion is how can I prove that for $\alpha \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ with, $d \in \Bbb Z$, $d$ square free, the following statement is true

$N(\alpha) = \pm1 \Leftrightarrow \alpha $ is a unit

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The norm is multiplicative.